# How to match specific accept headers in a route?

Tags: scala, spray

I want to create a route that matches only if the client sends a specific `Accept` header. I use Spray **1.2-20130822**.

I'd like to get the route working:

```
def receive = runRoute {
    get {
      path("") {
        accept("application/json") {
           complete(...)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/test/scala/spray/http/ContentNegotiationSpec.scala) I found a spec using an `accept()` function, but I can't figure out what to import in my Spray-Handler to make it work as directive. Also, I did not find other doc on header directives but these [stubs](https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/release/1.2/docs/documentation/spray-routing/header-directives).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
def acceptOnly(mr: MediaRange*): Directive0 =
  extract(_.request.headers).flatMap[HNil] {
    case headers if headers.contains(Accept(mr)) ⇒ pass
    case _                                       ⇒ reject(MalformedHeaderRejection("Accept", s"Only the following media types are supported: ${mr.mkString(", ")}"))
  } & cancelAllRejections(ofType[MalformedHeaderRejection])
```

Then just wrap your root:

```
path("") {
  get {
    acceptOnly(`application/json`) {
      session { creds ⇒
        complete(html.page(creds))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And by the way the latest spray 1.2 nightly is `1.2-20130928` if you can, update it

Comment: A tiny bug here: the string interpolation of `${mr: _*}` fails if more than one `MediaRange` are passed in and none of them are matched. If I change that to `${mr}` it runs, though the output contains the type of `mr` now which probably is not intended.

Comment: @rompetroll Sorry, didn't know that, thanks. You can replace `${mr: _*}` with `${mr.mkString(", ")}`

Answer (score 2):

There is no pre-defined directive called `accept` directive. You can see the full list of available directives [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/predefined-directives-alphabetically/).

However, you can use the `headerValueByName` directive to make a custom directive that does what you desire:

```
def accept(required: String) = headerValueByName("Accept").flatMap {
  case actual if actual.split(",").contains(required) => pass
  case _ => reject(MalformedHeaderRejection("Accept", "Accept must be equal to " + required))
}
```

Put this code in scope of your spray `Route`, then just use as you have shown in your question.

Comment: thank you that should work. Although I probably should change `if actual == required` to `if actual.split(",") contains required` or something like that.