# Spray routing: How to respond with different content-types?

Tags: scala, routes, http-headers, spray, http-accept-header

In spray I would like to respond with different content-types, depending on the given `Accept` header. I've seen a couple of suggestions in the [question by rompetroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131488/spray-routing-how-to-match-specific-accept-headers), but I would like to hear if there are any canonical way of doing it (i. e. simple or already implemented).

In essence what I imagine should happen is something like:

```
path("somepath") {
  get {
    // Find whatever we would like to return (lazily)
    ...
    // Marshall resource and complete depending on the `Accept` header
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spray is actually looking into the `Accept` header value and validates against it. So if route is returning `application/json` or `text/plain` and client accepts `image/jpeg` than spray will return `406 Not Acceptable`. If client will request `application/json` or`text/plain` from this route than he will receive repsonse with matching Content-Type.

The main trick here is to use correct marshallers for return objects.
You can read more about marshalling [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-httpx/marshalling/).

Also you can override MediaType with [respondWithMediaType](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-routing/respond-with-directives/respondWithMediaType/#respondwithmediatype) directive, but I think it is better to use correct marshallers.

Comment: That makes a lotta sense. I totally missed this from the documentation. Thanks :)

Comment: Agreed, `respondWithMediaType` is usually the wrong way to go. Marshallers already contain all the logic to do automatic content-type negotiation. See my answer how to combine marshallers for different content-types into one that accepts all of them and chooses the right marshaller for all of them.

Answer (score 15):

See the tests [in this commit](https://github.com/spray/spray/commit/0d8958bc7a8f0dc91ce29125db40f6cebd4e5851#diff-3).

I copied it here for reference:

```
case class Data(name: String, age: Int)
object Data {
  import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

  // don't make those `implicit` or you will "ambiguous implicit" errors when compiling
  val jsonMarshaller: Marshaller[Data] = jsonFormat2(Data.apply)
  val xmlMarshaller: Marshaller[Data] =
    Marshaller.delegate[Data, xml.NodeSeq](MediaTypes.`text/xml`) { (data: Data) ⇒
      <data><name>{ data.name }</name><age>{ data.age }</age></data>
    }

  implicit val dataMarshaller: ToResponseMarshaller[Data] =
    ToResponseMarshaller.oneOf(MediaTypes.`application/json`, MediaTypes.`text/xml`)  (jsonMarshaller, xmlMarshaller)
}
```

You then using `complete` should suffice in your route, content-type negotiation is automatically taken care of:

```
get {
  complete(Data("Ida", 83))
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but in the call  `jsonFormat2(Data.apply)` above, where is the `.apply` defined?

Comment: It's automatically generated by the Scala compiler for a `case class` to support the `Data(...)` syntax instead of needing to write `new Data(...)`.